# how to run a python script everyday by using at command?

Tags: at-job

I would like to run a python program everyday.
I figured out how to do at specific time.

```
sudo echo "python ./test.py" | at 6:00
```

However I don't know how to run this script everyday.

I tried this:

```
sudo echo "python ./test.py" | at 6:00 everyday
```

Then it didn't warn me anything, and it ran once, but when I checked `atq` afterwards, there is nothing there.
so it means it will not be run everyday.

How can I run a python script everyday ?
( I am using mac os x. )

Thank you.

Comment: more literature concerning MacOSX auto schedulers, including cron: http://superuser.com/questions/126907/how-can-i-get-a-script-to-run-every-day-on-mac-os-x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a cron to run your script.

Most People are using cronix for cron jobs on the mac, I believe...

You can get it here:
https://code.google.com/p/cronnix/

Comment: I also thought about using a cron,but since I read that a cron uses more CPU, I preferred to use an at command. but I will try it too.

Comment: ok then if you know how to use cron, could you please tell me ?